# I have problems installing graphics.h library for c in my Ubuntu devise

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, bgi

I tried following these steps I found online to install the graphics.h library for Linux: [The link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu)
But I get an error when doing the second part of the second step. Here is what it gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

Package guile-1.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'guile-1.8' has no installation candidate

E: Unable to locate package guile-1.8-dev

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'guile-1.8-dev'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'guile-1.8-dev'

E: Unable to locate package libesd0-dev
```

Comment: You've left a bit too much to the imagination, as there are not only multiple steps in that link, but also multiple sets of steps. It's not definite which set of steps is "these steps". *(Plus, questions should be self-contained. It should not be necessary to follow a link to get the gist of what you are doing.)* Please add to your question the specific command that produces this output.

Comment: Packages are often dependent on OS version. So a question like this should include which version of Ubuntu you are using. Especially since it looks like you might be following the instructions for Ubuntu versions earlier than 18.04. Versions of Ubuntu that old are no longer supported (unless you are in an extended support program for a slightly older LTS version) -- you might want to upgrade before installing new packages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.